# Scroll ante recarga de mensajes en un chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

Estoy construyendo una aplicación de mensajería en la web, usando `React`en frontend y `Django` en backend. El problema viene dado cuando el usuario carga mensajes antiguos dentro del chat scrolleando hacia arriba. Quiero lograr un resultado idéntico al de `Twitter` o `Whatsapp` cuando se cargan los mensajes o los twitts scrolleando hacia arriba. Pues bien , tengo el siguiente componente de React:

```
export function MessagesContainer({newMsg, messagesHistorialPage,noMoreMessages}){
const containerRef                                                  = useRef(null)
const oldScrollRef                                                  = useRef(null)
const navigate                                                      = useNavigate()
const clickedUser                                                   = useClickedUser((state)=>(state.clickedUser))
let [messagesHistorial, setMessagesHistorial]                       = useMessagesHistorial((state)=>([state.messagesHistorial, state.setMessagesHistorial]))
let [msgReceivedInChat,setMsgReceivedInChat]                        = useMsgReceivedInChat((state)=>([state.msgReceivedInChat,state.setMsgReceivedInChat]))
let [gottaScrollChat, setGottaScrollChat]                           = useGottaScrollChat((state)=>([state.gottaScrollChat, state.setGottaScrollChat]))
let messagesLoaderActivated                                         = useMessagesLoaderActivated((state)=>(state.messagesLoaderActivated))
const thersScroll = ()=>{
    return containerRef.current.scrollHeight > containerRef.current.clientHeight
}
const loadMessages = async ()=>{
    const response = await apiWrap(async ()=>{
        return await getMessagesHistorialAPI(clickedUser.id, getJWTFromLocalStorage().access, messagesHistorialPage.current)
    }, navigate, 'Cargando mensajes, espere', 1000, "getMessagesHistorial")
    if (response){
        if (response.status == 200){
            oldScrollRef.current = containerRef.current.scrollHeight
            messagesHistorialPage.current += 1
            updateMessagesHistorial(setMessagesHistorial, messagesHistorialPage, response.data !== "no_messages_between" ? response.data.messages_hist : [], messagesHistorial)
        } else if (response.status == 400){
            if (response.data.error == "no_more_pages"){
                noMoreMessages.current = true
            } else if (response.data.error == "error_while_getting_messages"){
                toast.error('¡ Ha habido un error cargando los mensajes !')
            }
        } else {
            toast.error('¡ Error inesperado cargando los mensajes !')
        }
    }
}
const sendMsg = async (data)=>{
    const response = await apiWrap(async ()=>{
        return await sendMsgAPI(clickedUser.id, data.msg, getJWTFromLocalStorage().access)
    }, navigate, 'Enviando mensaje, espere', BASE_NON_TOASTED_API_CALLS_TIMER, "sendMsg")
    if (response){
        if (response.status == 200){
            setMessagesHistorial([...messagesHistorial, response.data.sended_msg])
            setGottaScrollChat(true)
        } else {
            if (response.data.error == "same_user"){
                toast.error("Error inesperado enviando mensaje, cerrando sesión por seguridad")
                logoutUser(navigate)
            } else {
                toast.error('¡ Error inesperado enviando el mensaje !')
            }
        }
    }
}
const formatingFunction = (msg)=>{
    return <Message key={v4()} messageObj={msg}/>
}
const scrollHandler = async (e)=>{
    if (e.target.scrollTop <= 0){
        if (!noMoreMessages.current && thersScroll() ){  
            // la ultima condicion se pone para evitar que se llame a la api cuando no se ha scrolleado
            await loadMessages()
        }
    } else if ((event.target.scrollTop + event.target.clientHeight) >= (event.target.scrollHeight - 20)){
        setMsgReceivedInChat(false)
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    if (msgReceivedInChat && containerRef.current){
        if ((containerRef.current.scrollTop + containerRef.current.clientHeight) >= (containerRef.current.scrollHeight - 200)){
            setGottaScrollChat(true)
            setMsgReceivedInChat(false)
        }
    }
}, [msgReceivedInChat])

useEffect(()=>{
    if (containerRef.current){
        if (gottaScrollChat){
            if (thersScroll()){
                containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight
            }
            setGottaScrollChat(false)
        } else if (messagesHistorialPage.current > 1){
            // aca se modificara el scroll despues de cargar la nueva pagina
            containerRef.current.scrollTop += containerRef.current.scrollHeight - oldScrollRef.current
        }
    }
}, [messagesHistorial, gottaScrollChat])
useEffect(()=>{
    if (newMsg){
        (async function(){
            await sendMsg(newMsg)
        })();
    }
}, [newMsg])
return (
    <div className="messages-container">
        {
            messagesLoaderActivated ?
            <Loader big loaderActivated={messagesLoaderActivated}/>
            :
            <>
                {messagesHistorial.length !== 0 ?  
                    <div className="messages-list-container scrollbar-container" ref={containerRef} onScroll={scrollHandler}>
                        {messagesHistorial.map(formatingFunction)}
                    </div>
                    :
                    <h3 className="messages-container__title">
                        {clickedUser?
                            "No hay mensajes :("
                            :
                            "Selecciona un usuario para chatear"
                        }
                    </h3>
                }
            </>
        }
    </div>
)
}

MessagesContainer.propTypes = {
      newMsg : PropTypes.object,
      messagesHistorialPage : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      noMoreMessages : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
 }
```

La función `loadMessages` es la que se ejecutara cuando el usuario scrollee hacia arriba. Pues bien, cuando la api retorne la siguiente pagina de mensajes, estoy ejecutando la funcion `updateMessagesHistorial` (básicamente agrega los mensajes nuevos al principio de la lista en el state `messagesHistorial`), la cual provocara la ejecución de uno de los useEffect el cual setteara el scroll del contenedor a como estaba antes de cargar los mensajes.

El código que pase actualmente funciona, y logro el resultado que espero, sin embargo, la experiencia de usuario no es la mejor, ya que, cuando actualizo el valor del state (ejecutando `updateMessagesHistorial`), esto provoca un rerender del contenedor, por tanto van a haber unas milesimas de segundo en las cuales el scroll no sea el anterior sino que sea 0.

Por lo que he visto y probado, existe una forma de evitar este problema usando `insertAdjacentHTML`, sin embargo no es lo mas 'elegante' si estoy usando React. Existe alguna forma de evadir este problema usando React? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de estar trabajando en esto durante varios días, por fin logre resolverlo. Este es el código ...

```
export function MessagesContainer({newMsg, messagesHistorialPage,noMoreMessages}){
const containerRef                                                  = useRef(null)
const oldScrollRef                                                  = useRef(null)
const navigate                                                      = useNavigate()
const clickedUser                                                   = useClickedUser((state)=>(state.clickedUser))
let resetScroll                                                     = useRef(false)
let [messagesHistorial, setMessagesHistorial]                       = useMessagesHistorial((state)=>([state.messagesHistorial, state.setMessagesHistorial]))
let [msgReceivedInChat,setMsgReceivedInChat]                        = useMsgReceivedInChat((state)=>([state.msgReceivedInChat,state.setMsgReceivedInChat]))
let [gottaScrollChat, setGottaScrollChat]                           = useGottaScrollChat((state)=>([state.gottaScrollChat, state.setGottaScrollChat]))
let messagesLoaderActivated                                         = useMessagesLoaderActivated((state)=>(state.messagesLoaderActivated))
const thersScroll = ()=>{
    return containerRef.current.scrollHeight > containerRef.current.clientHeight
}
const loadMessages = async ()=>{
    const response = await apiWrap(async ()=>{
        return await getMessagesHistorialAPI(clickedUser.id, getJWTFromLocalStorage().access, messagesHistorialPage.current)
    }, navigate, 'Cargando mensajes, espere', 1000, "getMessagesHistorial")
    if (response){
        if (response.status == 200){
            containerRef.current.style.scrollBehavior = "auto"
            oldScrollRef.current = containerRef.current.scrollHeight
            resetScroll.current = true
            messagesHistorialPage.current += 1
            updateMessagesHistorial(setMessagesHistorial, messagesHistorialPage, response.data !== "no_messages_between" ? response.data.messages_hist : [], messagesHistorial)

        } else if (response.status == 400){
            if (response.data.error == "no_more_pages"){
                noMoreMessages.current = true
            } else if (response.data.error == "error_while_getting_messages"){
                toast.error('¡ Ha habido un error cargando los mensajes !')
            }
        } else {
            toast.error('¡ Error inesperado cargando los mensajes !')
        }
    }
}
const sendMsg = async (data)=>{
    const response = await apiWrap(async ()=>{
        return await sendMsgAPI(clickedUser.id, data.msg, getJWTFromLocalStorage().access)
    }, navigate, 'Enviando mensaje, espere', BASE_NON_TOASTED_API_CALLS_TIMER, "sendMsg")
    if (response){
        if (response.status == 200){
            setMessagesHistorial([...messagesHistorial, response.data.sended_msg])
            setGottaScrollChat(true)
        } else {
            if (response.data.error == "same_user"){
                toast.error("Error inesperado enviando mensaje, cerrando sesión por seguridad")
                logoutUser(navigate)
            } else {
                toast.error('¡ Error inesperado enviando el mensaje !')
            }
        }
    }
}
const formatingFunction = (msg)=>{
    return <Message key={v4()} messageObj={msg}/>
}
const scrollHandler = async (e)=>{
    if (e.target.scrollTop <= 0){
        if (!noMoreMessages.current && thersScroll() ){  
            // la ultima condicion se pone para evitar que se llame a la api cuando no se ha scrolleado
            await loadMessages()
        }
    } else if ((event.target.scrollTop + event.target.clientHeight) >= (event.target.scrollHeight - 20)){
        setMsgReceivedInChat(false)
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    if (msgReceivedInChat && containerRef.current){
        if ((containerRef.current.scrollTop + containerRef.current.clientHeight) >= (containerRef.current.scrollHeight - 200)){
            setGottaScrollChat(true)
            setMsgReceivedInChat(false)
        }
    }
}, [msgReceivedInChat])

useEffect(()=>{
    if (containerRef.current && resetScroll.current){ // si cambia el historial de mensajes por recarga al scrollear ... 
        containerRef.current.scrollTop += containerRef.current.scrollHeight - oldScrollRef.current
        resetScroll.current = false
        containerRef.current.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth"
    }
}, [messagesHistorial])
useEffect(()=>{
    if (containerRef.current && gottaScrollChat){
        if (thersScroll()){
            containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight
        }
    }
    setGottaScrollChat(false)
}, [gottaScrollChat])

useEffect(()=>{
    if (newMsg){
        (async function(){
            await sendMsg(newMsg)
        })();
    }
}, [newMsg])
return (
    <div className="messages-container">
        {
            messagesLoaderActivated ?
            <Loader big loaderActivated={messagesLoaderActivated}/>
            :
            <>
                {messagesHistorial.length !== 0 ?  
                    <div className="messages-list-container scrollbar-container" ref={containerRef} onScroll={scrollHandler}>
                        {messagesHistorial.map(formatingFunction)}
                    </div>
                    :
                    <h3 className="messages-container__title">
                        {clickedUser?
                            "No hay mensajes :("
                            :
                            "Selecciona un usuario para chatear"
                        }
                    </h3>
                }
            </>
        }
    </div>
)
}

MessagesContainer.propTypes = {
newMsg : PropTypes.object,
messagesHistorialPage : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
noMoreMessages : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a tu pregunta. Puede que para ti sea claro, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer].